# Get owner module from memory address

Tags: winapi, virtual-memory

I iterate trough my process memory using VirtualQuery, I would like to know witch module the certain memory range is owned by whom. Either the executable either some other dll, and get it's name.

Is there a way I can find out ?

Answer (score 8):

Yes, a module handle value in Windows is simply the base address of the VM allocation for the module.

So you can cast the MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION.AllocationBase you get back to (HMODULE) and pass that to GetModuleFileName().  Of course, do keep in mind that this only works for allocations that were made for code loaded from executable files.  You normally encounter lots of VM allocations with VirtualQuery() that are data or stacks.  They don't have an owner and are not associated with a module. You can filter pretty effectively from the protection flags, executable code from a module is not writable.

Comment: So dinamically allocated memory, stack (variables per general) can not have a module name. Correct ? Can VirtualQuery return a memory range that belongs to a module and some stack data or dinamically alocated memory?

Comment: Stack and heap memory is not associated with any particular module. Only memory used to hold an image of a loaded module is.